# For a 1view/scene to 2view/scene app, what application should I choose in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, view, scene

The question may be simple to some others, but I have been struggling with this for a while. The app I want would be like this: first scene/view with two big buttons (no toolbar item), click each one to get into two new scenes. So totally three scenes. In Xcode, what application should I choose? And in storyboard how/should I drag/draw? Thanks.

Update:
thanks for the link, the big-number-user.
I actually read that tutorial before I asked.
A little update on what I got so far:

1, I selected "single view", so there's view controller 1 (VC1) in the storyboard.

2, dragged a navigation controller (NC), and move the initial view arrow pointing to NC

3, control-drag to link NC and VC1, selected "relationship segue root view controller" when some small dialog popup. IS THIS CORRECT?

4, created two additional VC, VC3 and VC4, control-drag link each to NC. selected "push", IS THIS CORRECT?

5, in VC1, I added two buttons, showVC3 and showVC4. NOW I DON'T KNOW how to add IBAction to button showVC3 and showVC4. I tried to control-drag it to ViewController.m file @interface and @end section, but failed.
What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by selecting `Single View` based application in the Storyboard

For storyboard, refer to this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

You can find many other tutorials by just googling it.

---

The structure of your storyboard show be as follows:

```
Navigation Controller => VC1
```

Add buttons to VC1

```
- Button 1
- Button 2
```

Add VC3 and VC4 on the storyboard and segue as follows:

```
- Button 1 to VC3
- Button 2 to VC4
```

Comment: VC3 and VC4 show have segue from button1 and button2 of VC1. I have updated my answer to explain it.

Comment: wow, you are quite responsive answer! I'll "UP" for you, although I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Oh-yeah, I think I figured out. I'll answer my own question now.

1, I selected "single view", so there's view controller 1 (VC1) in the storyboard.

2, dragged a navigation controller (NC), and move the initial view arrow pointing to NC

3, control-drag to link NC and VC1, selected "relationship segue root view controller" when some small dialog popup. IS THIS CORRECT? --- I guess this is right.

4, created two additional VC, VC3 and VC4, control-drag link each to NC. selected "push", IS THIS CORRECT? --- should be right.

5, in VC1, I added two buttons, showVC3 and showVC4. NOW I DON'T KNOW how to add IBAction to button showVC3 and showVC4. I tried to control-drag it to ViewController.m file @interface and @end section, but failed. What should I do next? ----- I guess I can add IBAction to showVC3 and showVC4 buttons, but I could control-drag them to VC3 and VC4, respectively, and choose "push".

Ran the project, showVC3 and showVC4 buttons are shown, click them and I can go to VC3 and VC4!
I guess that's it. Hope this could be helpful to others who had question like mine.